# ssindex.cmd: indexing symbols from p4 - md5 mismatch

Tags: debugging, perforce, pdb

On the build server, right after compiling I am running ssindex.cmd (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff558878(v=vs.85).aspx) to index the pdbs'.

SC system is p4. SSindex runs 'p4 have' against the local files that have just been synced. It then calls PDBStr.exe to inject that info (including depot path and revision) into the corresponding pdbs'. This way when somebody opens a crash dump, Visual Studio will retrieve the pbds and download the revision of the source code embedded in the pdbs' themselves.

Well what happens is that Visual studio downloads (with 'p4 print') the revision of the file dictated by the pdb (I can see the local file whose revision is stored as part of its path) but then complains that MD5 of the just downloaded from p4 file does not match the md5 of the file that was used to build that very pdb.

VS only tells me the MD5 of the file just pulled from p4 but I have no way to see what's the MD5 to match.

I am running a slightly custom version of ssindex.cmd. The reason being that the original version of the script (that comes with Debugging Tools for win) does not like forwards slashes therefore I merely had to adjust a couple of reg exps to make it work (it would just report that 'p4 have' did not return any valid match). I am by no means touching the source code with the script so I cant really explain such a mismatch.

All the outputs looks good. By using 'Srctool.exe' (sts all files indexed within the .pdb file) pdbs' look good. They have the right revision for the code.

Any idea? The web has litterally no results on this.

Edited to clarify a few points

Comment: I was using thw wrong workspace, not the same I was using to sync the code. Some mean circumstances made it really hard to spot :(